# Mapstruct, mapping to nested objects from sevral input parameters

Tags: java, dto, mapstruct

Given a set of five objects:

```
KeyDto{String id}

ValueDto{String name, String value, String description}

Key{String id, String name}

Value{String value, String description}

Target{Key key, Value value}
```

I would like to create a mapper with two parameters:

```
 Target dtosToTarget(KeyDto keyDto, ValueDto valueDto);
```

However, just defining helper methods for Key and Value seems not to be enough:

```
@Mapping(source = "keyDto.id", target = "id")
@Mapping(source = "valueDto.name", target = "name")
Key keyDtoAndValueDtoToKey(KeyDto keyDto, ValueDto valueDto);

Value valueDtoToValue(ValueDto valueDto);
```

This gives an error on the actual dtosToTarget method:

Error:(17, 19) java: Can't map property "java.lang.String value" to "mapping.Value value". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "mapping.Value map(java.lang.String value)".

The only solution I could think of - is defining custom java expressions to call necessary methods, like

```
@Mapping(target = "key", expression = "java(keyDtoAndValueDtoToKey(keyDto, valueDto))")
@Mapping(target = "value", expression = "java(valueDtoToValue(valueDto))")
```

Is there a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because by default MapStruct will try to map `valueDto.value` into `Target.value` which is `String` to `Value`.

However, you can configure this like this:

```
@Mapper
public MyMapper {

    @Mapping( target = "key.id", source = "keyDto.id")
    @Mapping( target = "key.name", source = "valueDto.name")
    @Mapping( target = "value", source = "valueDto")
    Target dtosToTarget(KeyDto keyDto, ValueDto valueDto);

    Value valueDtoToValue(ValueDto valueDto);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
@Mapping(source = "valueDto.name", target = "name")
void keyDtoAndValueDtoToKey(@MappingTarget KeyDto keyDto, ValueDto valueDto);
```

This will keep all fields from Key Dto as it is and mapping required fields from valueDto as configured.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion.
This will map ValueDto.name to KeyDto.name. However KeyDto does not even have name. Correct target would be Key.name. 
But this does not solve an actual problem.
Maybe you can express it better on github: https://github.com/piddubnyi/mapstruct-mapping